# IntelliJ VCS log windows became empty

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control

Was observing nice version control log intellij for many weeks, but now it is gone:

[image]

What can be the reason?

**UPDATE**

The following exception is in log:

```
2016-10-27 11:22:55,164 [ 561002]  ERROR - .intellij.util.EventDispatcher - IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5  Build #IU-162.2228.15 
2016-10-27 11:22:55,164 [ 561002]  ERROR - .intellij.util.EventDispatcher - JDK: 1.8.0_45 
2016-10-27 11:22:55,164 [ 561002]  ERROR - .intellij.util.EventDispatcher - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
2016-10-27 11:22:55,164 [ 561002]  ERROR - .intellij.util.EventDispatcher - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2016-10-27 11:22:55,164 [ 561002]  ERROR - .intellij.util.EventDispatcher - OS: Windows 8 
2016-10-27 11:22:55,671 [ 561509]  ERROR - .intellij.util.EventDispatcher - Could not initialize class com.intellij.vcs.log.data.DataPack 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.intellij.vcs.log.data.DataPack
    at com.intellij.vcs.log.data.VcsLogRefresherImpl.<init>(VcsLogRefresherImpl.java:58)
    at com.intellij.vcs.log.data.VcsLogData.<init>(VcsLogData.java:90)
    at com.intellij.vcs.log.impl.VcsLogManager.<init>(VcsLogManager.java:80)
    at com.intellij.vcs.log.impl.VcsProjectLog$LazyVcsLogManager.compute(VcsProjectLog.java:142)
    at com.intellij.vcs.log.impl.VcsProjectLog$LazyVcsLogManager.getValue(VcsProjectLog.java:133)
    at com.intellij.vcs.log.impl.VcsProjectLog.createLog(VcsProjectLog.java:108)
    at com.intellij.vcs.log.impl.VcsLogContentProvider.initContent(VcsLogContentProvider.java:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ui.ChangesViewContentManager$MyContentManagerListener.selectionChanged(ChangesViewContentManager.java:278)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.dispatch(EventDispatcher.java:99)
    at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.access$200(EventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher$2.invoke(EventDispatcher.java:79)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.selectionChanged(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.ui.content.impl.ContentManagerImpl.a(ContentManagerImpl.java:603)
    at com.intellij.ui.content.impl.ContentManagerImpl.removeFromSelection(ContentManagerImpl.java:435)
    at com.intellij.ui.content.impl.ContentManagerImpl$1.run(ContentManagerImpl.java:504)
    at com.intellij.ui.content.impl.ContentManagerImpl.a(ContentManagerImpl.java:520)
    at com.intellij.ui.content.impl.ContentManagerImpl$$Lambda$806/142418469.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ExecutionCallback.setExecuted(ExecutionCallback.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ActionCallback.setDone(ActionCallback.java:72)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.d(FocusManagerImpl.java:289)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl$$Lambda$234/1242886840.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2397)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.b(FocusManagerImpl.java:287)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl$$Lambda$233/635644411.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ActionCallback$ExecutedExecutionCallback.doWhenExecuted(ActionCallback.java:187)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ActionCallback.doWhenDone(ActionCallback.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.a(FocusManagerImpl.java:287)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl$$Lambda$227/1465297832.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.e(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:631)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: You may want to check the log (`Help | Show Log in Explorer` menu item).

Comment: @BasLeijdekkers ah, yes, you are right, understood

Answer (score 0):

It might also be the case that the log pane somehow has a very small width making it look empty.

See [this report](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208353545/comments/360000086519).

I fixed it by removing all `vcs.log.*` tags from *options.xml* in the IntelliJ [settings directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) *([IntellijSettingsDirectory]/config/options)* and started IntelliJ again.

```xml
<application>
  <component name="PropertiesComponent">
    .......
    <!-- remove tags like these: -->
    <property name="vcs.log.changes.splitter.proportion" value="0.48878205" />
    <property name="vcs.log.details.splitter.proportion" value="0.3762058" />
    <property name="vcs.log.diff.splitter.proportion" value="0.26068377" />
  </component>
</application>
```